# How can you pass a function as an argument in AngularJS Emit?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using the emit function in AngularJS and was wondering if it's possible to pass in a function as an argument.

Parent Controller:

```
$scope.$on("getChildFunction", function(event, func) {
    console.log("function is...", func);
})
```

Child Controller:

```
$scope.$emit("getChildFunction", $scope.load_function());
```

However, when I use the web inspector func isn't returning at all. Are functions able to be passed up to the parent scope using emit?

Comment: are you trying to pass the function, or trying to pass the result of executing the function? i.e. does it work with `load_function` vs `load_function()`?

Comment: I am trying to pass the function @Claies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to pass the function itself, omit the parenthesis:

```
$scope.$emit("getChildFunction", $scope.load_function);
```

If you include the parenthesis - you'll execute the function and pass the *result* of the function.